# How to use configmap feature of kubernetes to store Kafka broker ip

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am developing an Kafka consumer and producer application. I have multiple kafka broker running in my environment. I want to use configmap feature of Kubernetes to store broker IP addresses and my consumer and producer app to use them in their config.
How do I go about it? any reference or sample code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean service/DNS name, and not IP?

You don't need a ConfigMap unless you want to create a `.properties` file, which the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods) shows how to create... Then mount in the Pod, and read that file in code.

For Kafka bootstrap server alone, you could simply use an environment variable on your pods.